# How To Open Outlook Task window from client side with javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, client-side

Not for IE users.

I want to Open the task window of outlook when the user click a button in my web page.

i mean without using the  `ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");`

and again, method that will work for all browsers especially FF or Chrome.

and i need it to be from the client side, not server side.

BTY: i assume the user is using office 2007

thanks

Comment: It's not possible, without writing some sort of browser addin that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Standards-supporting browsers don't support this proprietary behaviour, which opens up security holes anyway.